# Check if a variable/property is a single value or is an object/array

Tags: powershell

I want to loop through a bunch of objects and check each object's properties to see if it is a single value (string or int) or if it is an object/array (doesn't matter if it contains anything just see if it is an object or array).

I was going to just do a check to see if each property is a string or and integer, but is there a more efficient way?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$object -is [Array]
```

The `-is` operator checks whether an object is a certain type.

---

Edit: maybe what you want is to see if it's a [Value Type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch.aspx)?

```
$object.GetType().IsValueType
```

Update: [TamusJRoyce](https://stackoverflow.com/users/458321/tamusjroyce) mentioned in a comment that they didn't see an `.IsValueType` property, and suggested this, which is more idiomatic and might work in more situations:

```
$value -is [System.ValueType]
```

Comment: but does it make more sense to check whether it is an array OR an object or check if it is an integer or a string?

Comment: @red888 I don't think I understand your question. It would help if you had example code or even pseudocode in your question

Comment: @red888 see my edit, is that what you're looking for?

Comment: `$value -is [System.ValueType]` ($object.GetType() doesn't have IsValueType property for me)

Comment: Thanks @TamusJRoyce I like that better, and edited it into my answer. If you prefer to post it as a separate answer I'll remove that and link to yours.

Comment: I assume things have changed over time. That is helpful. Thanks @braintist!